# any command to release devices using pulseaudio

Tags: linux, alsa, openwrt, pulseaudio, mpd

i am totally new to pulse audio and alsa. the situation is this:

1. i have mpd compiled for alsa. this is embedded system and pulse audio plugin for mpd is not available.
2. when i DO NOT start pulse audio, mpd runs fine using alsa
3. as soon as i start pulse audio [ which is needed by bluetooth audio unfortunately ] , mpd / alsa stops working .

seems like, somehow pulse audio is grabbing the device and not letting it go . even after i stop pulse audio daemon .

Trying to run mpd afterwards gives me:

root@FINGI_GCC:~# mpc play
http://relay3.slayradio.org:8000/
[paused]  #1/1   0:00/0:00 (0%)
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
ERROR: problems opening audio device

So i was wondering how to reset pulse audio ? need to keep running pulse audio,mpd,alsa all on the same device..but not all at the same time.

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: PulseAudio will grab any device for exclusive use. Either kill PulseAudio as suggested by Emilien or use pasuspender to temporarily release control of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this audio device in in /dev/snd/, you could try to see which process is holding it with:

```
lsof /dev/snd/*
```

Then you could try to kill this process.

For instance when I'm running alsamixer, I get:

```
$ lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
...
alsamixer 7152 emilien    3u   CHR  116,5      0t0 10154 /dev/snd/controlC0
...
```